# Tuplas são realmente imutáveis em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t = (1,2,[4,6])
```

t é uma tupla. Se fizermos:

```
t[2][0]="e"
```

teremos:

```
(1, 2, ['e', 6])
```

Agora a tupla t é `(1, 2, ['e', 6])`

Não alteramos a tupla?

Seja `s= "stackoverflow"`

Não é possível fazer, por exemplo, `s[0] = "p"`

mas podemos fazer `s = "stackoverflowpt"`

Não alteramos s?

O que realmente significa o imutável em Python?